# Replace or modify file contents at one shot

Tags: files, ksh, aix, replace

I have file where I need to modify some lines for every account.

The line which I need to modify looks like as below:

`PstlInfo <some content>  NNYYYN` (Every account will have this line)

the `NNYYNN (always Y or N only 6 positions)` starts at the postion `150`
now for every account I need to modify only the above line starts with `PstlInfo` as below

`PstlInfo <some content>  NNNNNN` (whatever the above line I need to set as`NNNNNN`)

Every time I am doing it manually by opening file in `vi` editor, I want to change the only the contents which are starting from position `150` (5 positions only).

If there are few accounts it is easy to modify else it is very tedious job, is there any way that I can modify file at one shot where the line starts with `PstlInfo`

Comment: `sed -i.bak '/PstlInfo/s/[NY]\{6\}/NNNNNN/' file`?

Comment: @muru: AIX sed doesn't support inplace editing, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sed.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using AIX. It has a `sed` command which should be able to do the following:

```
sed '/^PstlInfo/s/^\(.\{150\}\)[NY]\{6\}/\1NNNNNN/' <yourfile >newfile
```

This replaces, on lines beginning `PstlInfo`, any 6 chars formed of N or Y (`[NY]\{6\}`) by NNNNNN, 
at position 150 chars (`^.\{150\}`) from the start of line. Those 150 chars are 
copied (`\(...\)`) and restored in the replacement string (`\1`).

Comment: other lines in the file copy to new file as is?

Comment: yes, by default sed just passes through the lines untouched. You can try the sed, then `diff yourfile newfile` will show you which lines changed.